# Trouble with Python3 string encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, airflow

I have link to CSV file with encoding windows-1251. Field `area_name` in this file is string. In Jupyter Lab on my laptop I doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(target_link, encoding="windows-1251", delimiter=";")
df['area_name'] = [el.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').replace('/', '') for el in df.area_name.values]
df.to_sql(...)
```

After this I have correct data in database
And when I use this code in Apache Airflow on server I have incorrect encoding in database
[image]

On my laptop:

- OS - macOS Monterey 12.1
- Python version 3.9.7
- Pandas version 1.3.4

On server:

- Python version 3.7.10
- Pandas version 1.1.4
- Airflow version 1.10.15

In both cases I use on database. It has encoding UTF8.
How fix encoding in pandas?

Comment: `el.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')` -- what's that supposed to achieve? Also, first you say the encoding in the DB is correct and after that incorrect. Which is it? Can you provide a [mcve] perhaps? Also, correct and incorrect are your interpretations, but what are the actual observations?

Comment: One of my attempts to guess the solution in desperation

Comment: when I run this code from my laptop in Jupyter lab in works correct and I can see correct Cyrillic letters in database and when this code run in airflow on server in database I see data like on attached screenshot. I can't understand where my mistake cause code example are equal in both cases